# Can i show message of Record not found in asp.net Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have made a grid view in asp.net, when there is no record, grid is not shown, i want that if there is no record, grid must be shown, but there must be a message, record not found with gridview headers available. I mean gridview must be there, but instead of rows there should be a message  in it, record not found, i have not used any code for fetching data in string, i just used datasource, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GridView` has an `EmptyDataText` property, where if there is no record found it will be displayed.

```
EmptyDataText="Record Not Found"
```

If you want to show the header of `GridView`, then you can make the `DataTable` have all the columns that are in your `DataSource` and add an Empty Row and bind that `DataTable` if your original `DataSource` does not contain data.

Answer (score 1):

You can display the custom text and format too.

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" 
        datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="true"
        emptydatatext="No data in the data source."
        runat="server">

        <emptydatarowstyle backcolor="LightBlue"
          forecolor="Red"/>

      </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
GridView1.EmptyDataText = "Record not found";
```